# Player with debut match perfect Hat-trick?

Tags: football, trivia

Over the years in football there have been many players who have scored hat-tricks in their clubs in their international debut matches.

For example: Serge Gnabry and Dieter Müller scored hat-tricks on their international debuts, Wayne Rooney on his Manchester United debut in 2004.

Is there any player who has scored a **perfect hat-trick**, which is achieved when a player scores one right-footed goal, one left-footed goal and one headed goal within one match, in debut match for a club or a country? If there is one who is he?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be many players with debut match perfect hat-tricks but the only one that I have found so far is **[Didier Drogba scoring perfect hat-trick on MLS debut](http://www.givemesport.com/627485-didier-drogba-scores-perfect-hattrick-on-full-mls-debut)** in a 4-3 win over Chicago Fire for Montreal Impact. [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cOoabvzUDrI)

There have been [33 perfect hat-tricks in premier league so far](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sport/football/article-4195712/Romelu-Lukaku-scored-Premier-League-hat-trick-300.html) but I'm not sure whether any of them is in debut match. [Players list](http://www.skysports.com/football/news/29210/9697785/martin-tylers-stats-and-facts-dismal-away-records-and-perfect-hat-tricks)

Other articles concerning perfect hat-tricks: [bleacherreport](http://bleacherreport.com/articles/2342872-5-stunning-examples-of-perfect-hat-tricks), [fifa](http://www.fifa.com/news/y=2011/m=4/news=handful-heroic-hat-tricks-1409096.html)

Answer (score 2):

Akwasi Asante scored perfect hat-trick on his debut for Chester FC in November 2018 against Darlington FC.

> Asante netted on 27 minutes with a header, followed by a left and then right foot effort in the second half ...

Reference: [Chester FC 3 Darlington 1: Sublime Akwasi Asante hat-trick](https://www.cheshire-live.co.uk/sport/football/match-reports/chester-fc-3-darlington-1-15492105)